# How to extract a function out of arr.map(elem => dict[elem])?

Tags: javascript, function, dictionary, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

*A function should do only one thing* is considered a good practice when writing functions. However, I have a function that is already very minimal, but nevertheless I *think* it can be further extracted, but I don't know how this can be done.

The following `recode()` function replaces array values according to a look-up dictionary.

```js
function recode(arr, dict) {
    return arr.map(elem => dict[elem])
}
```

Example to how it works:

```js
// input data to be recoded
const myArr = ['eggplant', 'tomato', 'carrot', 'cabbage'];

// look-up dictionary
const myDict = {
    eggplant: 'purple',
    tomato: 'red',
    carrot: 'orange',
};

const result1 = recode(myArr, myDict)
console.log(result1) // => ["purple", "red", "orange", undefined]
```

The way I see it, the current `recode()` function does two things:

1. It matches by identity (you might have a better description than this), i.e., `elem => dict[elem]`; and
2. it maps over `arr`

My question is whether I can extract an individual function for `elem => dict[elem]`, and supply that function to `arr.map()`. I imagine something along the lines of:

```js
// pseudo-code
function funcInner() {...}

function recode(arr, dict) {
    return arr.map(funcInner)
}
```

This way, I will have one function that does only the replacement, and another that only maps over `arr`.

---

EDIT

---

To address the comments, I would like to make an analogy. Let's consider a function that doubles array values.

```js
function doubleArray(arr) {
  return arr.map(x => x * 2)
}
```

Some folks here might say that `doubleArray()` is already doing one thing. However, we could still extract:

```js
const doubleNumber = x => x * 2;

function doubleArray2(arr) {
  return arr.map(doubleNumber)
}
```

As far as I understand, `doubleArray()` did two things (double & map), whereas `doubleArray2()` does only one thing (map) and `doubleNumber()` does one thing (doubles). Therefore, `doubleArray()` is not a meaningless refactoring.

Furthermore, once we have a function that does one thing, it promotes more accurate unit tests we can write for it.

Lastly, if we translated this code to *typescript* (which I didn't focus on in this question), then the input type in `doubleNumber()` is different than the input type in `doubleArray()`. So that's another reason why I would prefer to extract.

I'm very new to javascript, but this is the way I understand it. So my question about `recode()` was within this context.

Comment: This question boils down to how you count "things" that a function does. In my opinion, your original function already does just one thing.

Comment: `elem => dict[elem]` is already a function albeit an anonymous one, there is nothing stopping you from extracting it

Comment: If you break it up that much, `recode` is just calling `map` and not adding any functionality or clarity. So there is no reason for `recode` to exist in the first place.

Comment: Thanks all. I've updated my question and added more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

```
function recode(arr, dict) {
    return arr.map(elem => funcInner(elem,dict));
};

function funcInner(elem, dict) {
    return dict[elem];
}
```

But i agree with the others commenting on you question, this may be a little overkill. Your choice.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

In essence `recode` is being used a wrapper around [`arr.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). This could also be achieved by assigning `recode` to a function returned by calling the [`Function.bind()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

```
const recode = myArr.map.bind(myArr, elem => myDict[elem]);
```

`myArr` needs to be passed as the first parameter to bind the context of the array.

```js
// input data to be recoded
const myArr = ['eggplant', 'tomato', 'carrot', 'cabbage'];

// look-up dictionary
const myDict = {
    eggplant: 'purple',
    tomato: 'red',
    carrot: 'orange',
};
const recode = myArr.map.bind(myArr, elem => myDict[elem]);
const result1 = recode(myArr, myDict)
console.log(result1) // => ["purple", "red", "orange", undefined]
```

But perhaps it is simpler just to call `.map()` directly:

```js
// input data to be recoded
const myArr = ['eggplant', 'tomato', 'carrot', 'cabbage'];

// look-up dictionary
const myDict = {
    eggplant: 'purple',
    tomato: 'red',
    carrot: 'orange',
};
const result1 = myArr.map(elem => myDict[elem])
console.log(result1) // => ["purple", "red", "orange", undefined]
```

If there is a desire to have a user-supplied callback, then the [ES-6 default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) could be used:

```js
function recode(myArr, myDict, callback = elem => myDict[elem]) {
  return myArr.map(callback);
}
// input data to be recoded
const myArr = ['eggplant', 'tomato', 'carrot', 'cabbage'];

// look-up dictionary
const myDict = {
  eggplant: 'purple',
  tomato: 'red',
  carrot: 'orange',
};

const result1 = recode(myArr, myDict)
console.log(result1) // => ["purple", "red", "orange", undefined]

const result2 = recode(myArr, myDict, elem => myDict[elem] + 'a')
console.log(result2) // => ["purplea", "reda", "orangea", "undefineda"]
```

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation on [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71352495/218196): Have the other function return a function that can be used as callback for `Array#map`:

```
function createMapper(dict) {
  return elem => dict[elem];
}

function recode(arr, dict) {
    return arr.map(createMapper(dict));
}
```

But I would also question whether this is really an improvement over your original code.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to extract in your case, thats why arrow functions exist.